# Append multiple dummy objects to json array with jq

Tags: json, random, jq

Lets say this is my array :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Matias",
    "age": "33"
  }
]
```

I can do this :

```
echo "$response" | jq '[ .[] | select(.name | test("M.*"))] | . += [.[]]'
```

And it will output :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Matias",
    "age": "33"
  },
  {
    "name": "Matias",
    "age": "33"
  }
]
```

But I *cant* do this :

```
echo "$response" | jq '[ .[] | select(.name | test("M.*"))] | . += [.[] * 3]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:7): object ({"name":"Ma...) and number (3) cannot be multiplied
```

I need to extend an array to create a dummy array with 100 values. And I cant do it. Also, I would like to have a random *age* on the objects. ( So later on I can filter the file to measure performance of an app .

Comment: Have you tried `echo "$response" | jq 'while(length < 100; . += [.[0]])'`? jq doesn't have an internal `random` function btw

Comment: if you're not restricted to jq, I could have offered an alternative solution.

Comment: @Dimitry, Sure. Any tool will do. I was interested in jq but if that does not work, then anything can do.

Comment: @oguzismail that worked! ( except for the random part as you stated ), thanks!

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, if you're running `bash`, then you could use `jtc` (the `json` tool I developed): `<<<$response jtc -jw'[0]><F99' / -w[:][age] -eu echo '$RANDOM' \;` - it will deliver you the required json with random `age` (`bash` facilitates `$RANDOM`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently jq does not have a built-in randomization function, but it's easy enough to generate random numbers that jq can use.  The following solution uses `awk` but in a way that some other PRNG can easily be used.

```
#!/bin/bash

function template {
    cat<<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "Matias",
    "age": "33"
  }
]

EOF
}

function randoms {
    awk -v n=$1 'BEGIN { for(i=0;i<n;i++) {print int(100*rand())} }'
}

randoms 100 | jq -n --argfile template <(template) '
  first($template[] | select(.name | test("M.*"))) as $t
  | [ $t | .age = inputs]
'
```

#### Note on performance

Even though the above uses awk and jq together, this combination is about 10 times faster than the posted `jtc` solution using `-eu`:

<sub>`jq+awk:          u+s = 0.012s`</sub>

<sub>`jtc with -eu:    u+s = 0.192s`</sub>

Using jtc in conjunction with awk as above, however, gives u+s == 0.008s on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, -eu slows things down.